# Load Telerik MVC Grid State

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I'm having some issues Saving/Loading the State of a Telerik MVC Grid control.

I'm finding many examples using Kendo grids, however we do not have access or the resources to change our system to Kendo from the original Telerik MVC Grids.

I'm able to save & load the current State of a grid using a Cookie with the code below:

```
function setState() {
    var pricingGrid = $("#PricingGrid").data("tGrid");
    var dataSource = pricingGrid.dataSource;
    var state = JSON.stringify({
        page: pricingGrid.page,
        pageSize: pricingGrid.pageSize,
        sort: pricingGrid.orderBy,
        group: pricingGrid.groupBy,
        filter: pricingGrid.filterBy
    });

    $.cookie("pricingGridState", state);
}


function loadState() {
    var grid = $("#PricingGrid").data("tGrid");
    var state = JSON.parse($.cookie("pricingGridState"));
    if (state)
    {
        grid.sort(state.sort);
        grid.pageTo(state.page);
        grid.filter(state.filter);
    }
}
```

This code seems to do the trick, but it fires a Rebind call for each method(sort, pageTo, and filter). I'm planning on saving the state of multiple grids on the page, and would rather not have each of them rebind 3 times on page load.

In Kendo it looks like I'd be able to use the 'grid.dataSource.query' method, but I cannot seem to get anything like that working in Telerik MVC.

Any help is appreciated!

Note: I've also tried saving the State objects off of the grid.dataSource property, but these do not seem to Load the grid State at all.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I am able to find a solution that worked for me. Here is what I did:

```
//Prevent auto binding of grid and load state from cookie
var gridsToBind = [];    
function CommonGrid_onDataBinding(e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.target.id, gridsToBind) == -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
        gridsToBind.push(e.target.id);
        LoadGridState();
    }
}    
function LoadGridState() {
    var grid = $("#CommonGrid").data('tGrid');
    var state = $.cookie("gridState");
    if (state) {
        state = JSON.parse(state);
        grid.currentPage = state.currentPage;
        grid.orderBy = state.orderBy;
        grid.filterBy = state.filterBy;
        grid.pageSize = state.pageSize;
        for (var i in state.filteredCols) {
            if (state.filteredCols.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                grid.columns[i].filters = state.filteredCols[i].filters;
                $("a[href*='=" + grid.columns[i].member + "-'").siblings(".t-grid-filter").addClass("t-active-filter");
            }
        }
        $("#CommonGrid").data('tGrid', grid);
    }
    grid.ajaxRequest();        
}

//Logic to save state of grid in cookie
function CommonGrid_OnDataBound(e) {
    var filteredCols = {};
    $.each(grid.columns, function (i, n) {
        if (!!n.filters) {
            filteredCols[i] = n;
        }
    });
    var state = JSON.stringify({
        currentPage: grid.currentPage,
        orderBy: grid.orderBy,
        filterBy: grid.filterBy,
        pageSize: grid.pageSize,
        filteredCols: filteredCols
    });
    $.cookie("gridState", state);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I applied previous examples Sanjeev Rai: it need some adjustment when used on Telerik Grid working with

```
.DataBinding(o =>
    {
        o.Ajax().Select(ajaxSelectActionName, controllerName);
    })
```

I this case the last row `grid.ajaxRequest();` in `function LoadGridState()` should be commented to avoid recursion. 
Otherwise, solution is very gracefull.
Thank you